# Windows 7 batch file: Why are these IF blocks keeping me from assigning variables to a value?

Tags: batch-file, prompt

Here's the broken batch file:

```
@echo off
if prod==prod (
    if xps==xps (
        set i1=prodxpsi1
        set i2=prodxpsi2
        set e1=prodxpse1
        set e2=prodxpse2
    ) else (
        set i1=prodzpsi1
        set i2=prodzpsi2
        set e1=prodzpse1
        set e2=prodzpse2
    )

    if 1==1 (
        echo %i1%, %i2%, %e1%, %e2%
    ) else (
        echo %i1%, %i2%, %e1%, %e2%
    )
)

pause
```

However, when I take out the outer `if prod==prod` block like this, it works:

```
@echo off
if xps==xps (
    set i1=prodxpsi1
    set i2=prodxpsi2
    set e1=prodxpse1
    set e2=prodxpse2
) else (
    set i1=prodzpsi1
    set i2=prodzpsi2
    set e1=prodzpse1
    set e2=prodzpse2
)

if 1==1 (
    echo %i1%, %i2%, %e1%, %e2%
) else (
    echo %i1%, %i2%, %e1%, %e2%
)

pause
```

When I run the batch file the first time, it echoes `, , ,`.  When I run it the second time, it works fine:

[image: lolwut]

Comment: I screwed up my first answer by accidentally throwing i1, i2, e1, and e2 into my environment. My new answer should be what you're looking for!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a quirk of the command parser.  Because of the brackets, it sees everything from `if ...` to `)` as one line.  When it reads this "one line", it expands all the variables to their values before processing any of it.  The `set` commands all occcur after the variables have been expanded.

There are two solutions: branches and delayed exansion.

**Branches:** Ensure the `set` commands and `echo` commands are not in the same set of top-most brackets:

```
@echo off
if not prod==prod goto :end
if xps==xps (
    set ...
) else (
    set ...
)
if 1==1 (
    ...
)
:end
pause
```

**Delayed Expansion:** This causes variables to be expanded as needed, rather than in advance.  Use the command `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` to activate this mode, use ! marks to refer to a variable in this manner, and use the command `EndLocal` when you're done.  Note that `EndLocal` will forget any variables declared after `SetLocal`, so you may want to move `SetLocal` to after the `set` commands.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if prod==prod (
    if xps==xps (
        set i1=prodxpsi1
        ...
    ) else (
        set i1=prodzpsi1
        ...
    )
    if 1==1 (
        echo !i1!, !i2!, !e1!, !e2!
    ) else (
        echo !i1!, !i2!, !e1!, !e2!
    )
)
endlocal
pause
```

Comment: Exactly my thoughts. Delayed expansion.

Comment: N.B. "goto :EOF" is equivalent to "go to the end of the file." It's also used to "return" from batch "subroutines," as in "call :mySub".

Comment: @BillP3rd: Nice!  I tend to use `Exit /B` for the same purpose.

Comment: And I learned something too... Your method can set ERRORLEVEL. Cool!

Comment: Brilliant!  How could one ever know something like this?

Answer (score 3):

If you enable delayed expansion, then use `!var!` syntax to reference the variables, then it behaves as you expect.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if prod==prod (
    if xps==xps (
        set i1=prodxpsi1
        set i2=prodxpsi2
        set e1=prodxpse1
        set e2=prodxpse2
    ) else (
        set i1=prodzpsi1
        set i2=prodzpsi2
        set e1=prodzpse1
        set e2=prodzpse2
    )

    if 1==1 (
        echo !i1!, !i2!, !e1!, !e2!
    ) else (
        echo !i1!, !i2!, !e1!, !e2!
    )
)
```

The help text (`cmd /?`) explains:

> /V:ON -- Enable delayed environment variable expansion using ! as the
>           delimiter. For example, /V:ON would allow !var! to expand the
>           variable var at execution time.  The var syntax expands
>   variables at input time, which is quite a different thing when inside of
>   a FOR loop.
>
> If delayed environment variable expansion is enabled, then the
>   exclamation character can be used to substitute the value of an
>   environment variable at execution time.

When you wrap the whole thing in an `if` statement, the whole block becomes essentially a single command. All the variables inside the command are expanded at the time of input, which is before the `if xps==xps` part begins. At that point in the script, the variables have not yet been defined.

By using the `!var!` syntax along with delayed expansion, then the value of `!i1!` isn't evaluated until that particular line is executed.

Thanks! Your question taught me something today!

Answer (score 0):

the whole `cmd` stuff works more like a preprocessor which runs the file once, creates the preprocessed 'real' file and then runs that. this means that `cmd` does not (re)evaluate dynamically set variables (or `for` loops based upon the changing content of a 'variable'.

since your description of the problem is a bit vague: do you use variables instead of the strings 'prod' and 'xps' and expect dynamic interpretation of these 'variables'?

Comment: Actually, batch files are not "preprocessed" all at once. They're read and processed one line at a time. This is easy to demonstrate. Where delayed expansion comes into play is where multiple lines are read as a single line, as in: if 1==1 (foo & bar & baz). The contents of the () will be read at once but nothing following.

Comment: @BillP3rd: but the effect for 'for'-loops is as IF it would be preprocessed and a gigantic preprocessed batch file (then one line at a time) is executed.

Comment: @akira, I think what you mean is each line and bracketted block is preproccessed.  With matching brackets at the start and end, then yes, it preprocesses the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

The following programs are simple illustrations of using, within an IF statement, the value of a variable set within the same statement. They are are intended to display ‘aa’ if no parameter is entered, and ‘bb’ if a parameter is entered. Example 1 displays only ‘a’ if there is no parameter. The other examples all work correctly.

In my opinion, Example 2, which uses ‘goto’s, is the most straightforward and easiest to understand.

Examples 2, 5, and 6 work by taking the troublesome code out of the IF statement.

```
@echo off & setlocal enableextensions & :: 1
if "%1" equ "" (
   set x=a
   set y=%x%
   ) else (
   set x=b
   set y=b
   )
echo %x%%y%
```

---

```
@echo off & setlocal enableextensions & :: 2
if "%1" neq "" goto 10
   set x=a
   set y=%x%
   goto 20
   :10
   set x=b
   set y=b
:20
echo %x%%y%
```

---

```
@echo off & setlocal enableextensions & :: 3
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if "%1" equ "" (
   set x=a
   set y=!x!
   ) else (
   set x=b
   set y=b
   )
endlocal & set "x=%x%" & set "y=%y%"
echo %x%%y%
```

In the following example, note the ‘setlocal’ in the ‘else’ block. This matches the ‘endlocal’, so that the variables ‘x’ and ‘y’ stay local to the program. (Otherwise, the ‘endlocal’ cancels the ‘setlocal’ on the first line.)

```
@echo off & setlocal enableextensions & :: 4
if "%1" equ "" (
   set x=a
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   set y=!x!
   ) else (
   set x=b
   set y=b
   setlocal
   )
endlocal &  set "y=%y%"
echo %x%%y%
```

---

```
@echo off & setlocal enableextensions & :: 5
if "%1" equ "" (
   call :seta
   ) else (
   call :setb
   )
echo %x%%y%
exit /b
:seta
   set x=a
   set y=%x%
   exit/b
:setb
   set x=b
   set y=b
   exit/b
```

---

```
@echo off & setlocal enableextensions & :: 6
set x=a
if "%1" equ "" (
   set y=%x%
   ) else (
   set x=b
   set y=b
   )
echo %x%%y%
```